# How to navigate in ReactJs singlepage app without using Link?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, onclick, components, react-router

In react, What is the equivalent of using a `<Link>` in an onClick function?
I want to create a react component inside a single page app, When a user presses anywhere on the components DOM, it has the same as the `<Link>` or `<a href >` behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put an `onClick` at the top of the document if you want. The click event will bubble using normal event rules and you can access `event.target` to find the origin. From there you can call `window.location.href = 'some-path'` to emulate the experience.